# multiple security:custom-authentication-provider

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, openid, spring-security

In applicationContext.xml,  it is valid to defined mmultiple  security:custom-authentication-provider  ?

for example

> `<bean id="dummyAuthenticationProvider"
>           class="com.user.sample.gwtspring.server.security.JDBCDummyAuthenticationProvider">
>           <security:custom-authentication-provider />
>       </bean>`
>
> `<bean id="dummyAuthenticationProvider2"
>           class="com.user.sample.gwtspring.server.security.OpenIdDummyAuthenticationProvider2">
>           <security:custom-authentication-provider />
>       </bean>`

will both be registered inside authenticationManager? I am thinking of using dummyAuthenticationProvider2 as openId. what other metaconfig i need to put inside applicationContext.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both authentication providers will be registered with authentication manager. No other config is required.

Answer (score 0):

It should register both providers with the authentication  manager.  When automatically configured the auth manager is set up with a list of providers to perform authentication (anonymous provider, remember me provider, etc..)

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/authentication-common-auth-services.html